# avahi process maxing out 18 CPUs on VM

Tags: networking, security, dns, avahi, htop

I'm not quite sure what the avahi process does, I see from searching that it "facilitates service discovery on a local network via the mDNS/DNS-SD protocol suite" and I understand it comes default on Ubuntu, but I can't imagine the usage I'm seeing is normal. It is taking 1800% of my CPU, basically maxing out 18 CPUs and running a bash command as you can see here in `htop`:

[image: htop screenshot]

I am thinking I might be compromised and that my machine may be acting as a DDOS attack bot or something, but is there any other reason this could be running in such a way or how to stop it. I killed the process and it stopped for around 30 minutes then restarted.

Any suggestions for how to debug or how to kill it and ensure it doesn't return?

Comment: Maybe you can extract some ideas from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/1799265) and/or even add to the bug report itself.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this or discover more about it? It definitely looks suspicious.. (all those bash subprocesses...)

Comment: I ended up first disabling the process `systemctl disable avahi-daemon` which didn't help, then removing it `apt-get remove avahi-daemon` which still didn't help, and then I just removed the whole user `deluser avahi` and that finally worked and I've been monitoring since then and the process hasn't restarted.